# How to generate numbers with strange pattern in C++

Tags: c++, logic

I was wondering if there is an efficient way to generate a set of these 4 numbers in C++:

```
(0,2,1,0) ; // A
(1,2,2,0) ; // B
(2,2,3,0) ; // C
(4,1,0,3) ; // D
(4,2,5,0) ; // E
(5,1,1,3) ; // F
(5,2,6,0) ; // G
(6,1,2,3) ; // H
(6,2,7,0) ; // I
(7,1,3,3) ; // J
(8,1,4,3) ; // K
(8,2,9,0) ; // L
(9,1,5,3) ; // M
(9,2,10,0) ; // N
(10,1,6,3) ; // O
(10,2,11,0) ; // P
(11,1,7,3) ; // Q
(12,1,8,3) ; // R
(12,2,13,0) ; // S
(13,1,9,3) ; // T
(13,2,14,0) ; // U
(14,1,10,3) ; // V
(14,2,15,0) ; // W
(15,1,11,3) ; // X
(16,1,12,3) ; // Y
(16,2,17,0) ; // Z
(17,1,13,3) ; // A1
(17,2,18,0) ; // B1
(18,1,14,3) ; // C1
(18,2,19,0) ; // D1
(19,1,15,3) ; // E1

" 16  Y  12  R  8  K  4  D  0"    
"  Z      S     L     E     A"    
" 17 A1  13  T  9  M  5  F  1"    
" B1      U     N     G     B"    
" 18 C1  14  V  10 O  6  H  2"    
" D1      W     P     I     C"    
" 19 E1  15  X  11 Q  7  J  3"
```

Consider the numbers in the above figure as a square piece and the alphabets A to E1 as intersection of adjacent square edges.In the above list ,every set(A,B,C..) has 4 numbers .  Numbers at position 1 and 3 represent the square piece number. Numbers at position 2 and 4 represent the type of square edge ( top - 0 , right - 1, bottom - 2, left - 3 ). The first set of number represents the intersection A. It is the intersection between square number 0 (bottom edge -- 2) and square number 1 (top edge -- 0) as shown in the above diagram.So, A is 0,2,1,0 .

Similarly, B is intersection of Square piece 1 ( bottom edge -- 2 ) and square piece 2 (top edge -- 0). Hence B is (1,2,2,0). Similarly C is (2,2,3,0) --intersection of square piece 2 (bottom edge - 2) and square piece 3 (top edge - 0)

The question is how to generate these numbers in C++

Comment: It would be trivial to implement as soon as you figure out formula or algorithm for this. Once you do that, SO would be happy to help you.

Comment: @mvp : ok, i will update when i could figure it out.

Comment: It's pretty trivial. Do you understand `for` loops in C++? What part is giving you trouble?

Comment: @Beta: The first 2 numbers have the form : x,1  ;  x,2  ; x+1,1  ; x+2,2 . The second two numbers have the form x,0  ;  y,3  ; x+1 ,0  ; y+1 , 3. But , after 3 steps , the pattern shifts a bit. This part is giving me trouble.

Comment: **Do you understand `for` loops in C++?**

Comment: @Beta: Yes, I understand for loop. for ( i = intialisation value ; i < maximum value ; i++ (incrementing) ) {...} . But, I am not able to make the link or connection. In other words, I am facing diificulty in implementing for loop for this problem. If it is very simple, please apologise me as I am a student and learning the concepts.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to iterate over the array by row and column:

```
 4  3  2  1  0
---------------
16 12  8  4  0 | 0
17 13  9  5  1 | 1
18 14 10  6  2 | 2
19 15 11  7  3 | 3
```

For example, column 1 and row 2 means square 6.

To iterate over the squares this way in the correct order we use nested loops like this:

```
int num_cols = 5;
int num_rows = 4;
for(int col=0; col<num_cols ; ++col)
{
  for(int row=0; row<num_rows ; ++row)
  {
    cout << "this is column " << col << ", row " << row << endl;
  }
}
```

Now we just have to figure out what to do in a particular location. What is the number of the square? You should see easily that it is `col*num_rows + row`. And the number of the square *below* (if there is one) is `col*num_rows + row + 1`, and the number of the row *to the right* (if there is one) is `(col-1)*num_rows + row`. So for example, if `col` is 1 and `row` is 2, the edges to report are

```
(6,1,2,3)
(6,2,7,0)
```

Is that enough?

Comment: Thank you. This is sufficient. I will take care from now.